# hash tag is not removing from url AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, hash, angular-ui-router

I am creating a static site using angular 1. I done routing with `ui-router`.
Now I want to remove # tag from the url.

I googled it and got solution to enable html5 mode.
I done it as below:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5mode= true;
})
```

and in index.html is added `<base href="/">`  but its not working.
and when i hitt `localhost/myapp/` its showing `Internal server error`.
Please help me how to fix it.

Comment: Provied your anchoring elements, show what exactly your route url becomes.

Comment: when i start my app it is `localhost/myapp/#/`

Comment: Did you follow the solution given by therobinkim ?

Comment: No.... he is talking about to rewrite url on server side... but I am not using any server side script. Its just a static site.

Comment: Why you want to remove `#` from url?

Comment: for SEO purpose.... and it should look like regular url

Comment: Wiil you provide plunker to see what exactly the `Internal server error` is.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UB5adcvw9zOOXAqtAkA5?p=preview Please check this plnkr link and let me know if we can do something

Comment: Why you are not using `ui-sref` instead using `href` ?

Comment: where? ... In which line?

Comment: In index.html file.

Comment: No..... not working

Comment: `Change the $locationProvider.html5Mode = true;`  to  `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: its showing errors of css and js files are not found... because its not finding root file

Comment: url should be `localhost//myapp/css/style.css` but its showing `localhost/css/style.css`

Comment: Index file and css file in same directory or not

Comment: index.html is in root folder and css, js are in assets folder

Comment: Then your link should be like `<link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`. Same for js too.

Comment: yes.... it is same .... but its not working when i m using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: It is working fine for me from plunker.

Comment: Can you plz do it in my plunkr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130940/discussion-between-sai-and-saurabh-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Once you enable html5mode, you will need to rewrite your server.

Without html5mode, your browser would be making a request to `http://localhost/` when the URL bar read `http://localhost/#/myapp/` (because the browser doesn't send anything after the `#` symbol).

With html5mode, now that the `#` symbol is gone, the browser is making a request to `http://localhost/myapp/`, which your server may not be configured to handle.

Here's a resource that might help you out: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: if I am not using any server side script... I mean its a static site .. then what to do?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Then you may just have to leave the `#` in there

Comment: but it will effect on SEO of the website.